# Python OrderedDict with dictionary within list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list that has multiple dictionaries inside of it. I'm trying to use `OrderedDict()` to accomplish iterating through the dictionary/list combo in the given order. However, I am aware how to use `OrderedDict`, however I am unaware how to use `OrderedDict()` to make a ordered dictionary that's inside an list. the following with the format of `storeItems`. The idea is to be able to iterate through the list using `for item in storeItems: for key in item: return key, item[key]` Here's what I have.

```
storeItems = OrderedDict()
#not sure how to declare the following list into OrderedDict() format
#the original dict/format to follow
#storeItems = [{
#        "Name": "Auto-Enter",
#        "Price": 30,
#        "Max": 100
#    }, {
#        "Name": "Multiplier",
#        "Price": 100,
#        "Max": 5
#    }, {
#        "Name": "Factory",
#        "Price": 200,
#        "Max": 3
#    }]
```

Any ideas?

## Edit

Expected output should be the following (If I were to `print()` and not `return`):

```
Name: Auto-Enter
Price: 30
Max: 100
Name: Multiplier
Price: 100
Max: 5
Name: Factory
Price: 200
Max: 3
```

So that with (a excluded function), I could find out if the given user `input().upper()` matches a item throughout the list, and if so, `return True`.

Comment: **accomplish this**?be more specific

Comment: So what would be the keys and values?

Comment: @kasramvd Edited question with the loop I'm using. Since it returns the dictionary in a random order, I'm trying to make it return in the order it's declared in the given format.

Comment: @sam2090 Edited with fix

Comment: @TheGamingHideout Can you add your expected output to your question?

Comment: @Kasramvd Edited question

Comment: i dont think `OrderedDict` will be helpful in this case. See answer posted by @Kasramvd. Python `lists` have persistent order but `dict` dont so `OrderedDict` is helpful in those cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can not create a dictionary with duplicate keys the `OrderedDict` is not what you want and note that you can no't get an order like what you want from your dictionaries because if you want to extract your items by order you should stored your items in an `OrderedDict` at first.

If you want to get the items by printing you can simply convert your dictionaries to an unified string using `str.join()` method :

```
>>> print('\n'.join(['\n'.join(['{}:{}'.format(i,j) for i,j in d.items()]) for d in storeItems]))
```

Demo :

```
>>> print('\n'.join(['\n'.join(['{}:{}'.format(i,j) for i,j in d.items()]) for d in storeItems]))
Price:30
Max:100
Name:Auto-Enter
Price:100
Max:5
Name:Multiplier
Price:200
Max:3
Name:Factory
```